# Reduce Regions, some features dont contains centroid of pixel, in consecuence extracts of min or max obtains null value

Tags: javascript, raster, google-earth-engine

I have some problems to extract min or max statistcs from stack image to FeatureCollection.

*----var results_max = ee.Image(lc_stack).select(bandas).reduceRegions(fc ,ee.Reducer.max(),10);*

**Specification of problem**

1 When  i use **min or max reducers**, features which don´t contain centroid of pixel, appears like 
        null value (Like Feature 0, ID = 2379127 ). Conversly, features  that contain centroid appear 
        with values of  min and max statistics (Like Feature 0, ID = 2379128 ).

2 On  the other hand, when i use mean or count reducers, statistics are obteined by proportional 
         area, so we don't have problems with null values.

**WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO OBTAIN**

**Main objective: Statistics of min or max, but wihout null values, i'm not interested in modify 'tileScale'**

If it is impossible to do, i would like to extract mean values **BUT ONLY** for features which 
can´t obtain data for min or max. And export data like unique csv file if it's possible.

code link : https://code.earthengine.google.com/114d01347161e118818b1baf69fcf5fc

Thank you for your time, have a nice day.